# Smooth touchpad scrolling in GLFW

Tags: lwjgl, glfw

I'm using `glfwSetScrollCallback` in LWJGL (3.2.3) to handle scrolling.

Normally, scrolling on my touchpad is very precise (in Chrome, I can move my fingers down a very small amount to scroll down a very small amount), but with LWJGL, my scroll callback is called less frequently (I have to drag down more across the touchpad before the callback gets called, with a `yoffset` of `-1.0`).

Is there any way I can get LWJGL to work with my touchpad's smooth scrolling?